# Making a $http.put with query param, path param and body

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to call a API service something like url/1?param1=&param2=
it also expects a body(request payload) using `$http.put`.

Can anyone tell me how to do it in a efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use `param:` use `data:` in your config object.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass both parameters (in the query string) and a request body like this

```js
$http({
            url: "url",
            method: "put",
            params: {
                param1: value1,
                param2: value2
            }
            data: JSON.stringify(objectContainingBody)
        }).then(.....)
```

Comment: Will params also handle query parameters and path parameters

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this :

```
$http.put('url/path', payload, { params: { param1: 1, param2: 2 } }).then(
    function(response) {
        // access data with response.data
    },
    function(error) {
        // do something with the error
    }
);
```

If you need to convert your payload to json : `angular.toJson(payload)`.

You can look at AngularJS [$http.put](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put) for reference.